# undefined: proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I get `: ../.../...pb.go:21:11: undefined: proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3`
I want it to Version 2

I installed `protoc` from `https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases $ protoc --version` gives `libprotoc 3.6.0`. I also installed `golang-goprotobuf-dev` from `apt`.

Questions:

1. protoc (protobuffer compiler compiles always to version Proto3?)
2. What is the additional go support required?
3. How can I get a compiler that compiles to Proto2?
4. I noticed in one system libproto 3.6.1 compiles to proto2, I don't understand this.

Comment: I installed protoc3.7 by brew which results in the problem. How foolish I am

Answer (score 8):

1. protoc (protobuffer compiler compiles always to version Proto3?)

   It depends on your protobuf version and your protoc-gen-go version.
2. What is the additional go support required?

   I think you'll need to install [protoc-gen-go](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)
3. How can I get a compiler that compiles to Proto2?

   Install specific version of protoc-gen-go

   ```
   GIT_TAG="v1.2.0" # change as needed
   go get -d -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
   git -C "$(go env GOPATH)"/src/github.com/golang/protobuf checkout $GIT_TAG
   go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
   ```
4. I noticed in one system libproto 3.6.1 compiles to proto2, I don't understand this.

   Not sure about this one, but if I remember correctly, the determining factor is your protoc-gen-go version.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The same issue is happening to me as mentioned in your 4th point. How to resolve that.

Answer (score 2):

if you have encountered the following error:

```
   undefined: proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3
```

its because the protoc-gen-go's version not correct.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/golang/protobuf
 $ cd ~/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
 $ git checkout tags/v1.2.0 -b v1.2.0
 $ go install
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran this:

```
go get github.com/gogo/protobuf
```

Basically it updated `github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.2.1` to `github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.1`